Связь многие ко многим работает выборочно
Имеется три класса
class A
{
 public ICollection<B> Bs {get;set;} = [];
 public ICollection<C> Cs {get;set} = [];
}

class B
{
 public ICollection<A> As {get;set;} = [];
}

class C
{
 public ICollection<A> As {get;set;} = [];
}

И два одинаковых метода добавления сущности в бд
public Task<D<ADTO>> AddA(ADTO dto)
{
 var a = Transformer.ToEntity(dto);
 a.Bs.Add(await _repository<B>.Get(b => b.Id == 1));
 await _repository<A>.Add(a);
}

AddA добавляет строчку в таблицу BA.
Пробовал сделать аналогично для CA:
public Task<D<CDTO>> AddC(CDTO dto)
{
 var c = Transformer.ToEntity(dto);
 c.As.Add(await _repository<A>.Get(a => a.Name == "name"));
 await _repository<C>.Add(c);
}

Но почему - то здесь так не получается.  Как быть с таблицей CA?

Что значит "не получается"? Код не компилируется? Не запускается? Вылетает с ошибкой? С какой ошибкой?

Вы совершенно неправильно используете репозиторий. Почему вы извне дёргаете по два его метода? Добавьте в сам репозиторий метод Add*, внутри которого работайте только с DbContextом.

В общем, сделал связывание через entry.Entity.Property.Add(context.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1). Надеюсь, что так правильнее, по крайней мере все связи теперь нормально добавляются в таблицы. Просто изначально метод AddA нормально работал, т.е. добавлял запись в таблицу BA, а вот AddC не добавлял запись в таблицу CA.
